# ngModelChange with input length

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-template

I want to set a limit on the number of integers in an input field just like maxlength when type is text. Below is the code in my template.

```
  <ion-input 
      type="number" 
      placeholder="Username (required)" 
      [ngModel]="test"
      (ngModelChange)="getLength($event)"
      name="test"> 
  </ion-input>
```

In .ts,

```
  getLength(data){
    if(data.length > 8){
      console.log(1);
      let data1 = data.substring(0,8);
      this.test = data1; 
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Any idea how to prevent the event keypress when length is greater than 8.

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: why don't use maxlength attribute itself..

Comment: Hello,maxlength does not exist for type number.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FormBuilder` to perform more complex validation, it'll save you a lot of time and effort.

```
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

public myForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(8)]]
});
```

And then use it like:

```
<!-- Swap div for whatever your parent container is -->
<div>
  <ion-input type="number" formControlName="username">
</div>
```

Then you just check validity of the form with:

```
this.myForm.valid
```

Which will evaluate to either `true` or `false` depending on whether it's valid or not.

**EDIT:** To add to my answer above, you can use a pipe:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'maxLength'
})

export class MaxLength implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): string {

    if (value) {
      return value.length > 8 ? value.splice(0, 8) : value;
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this so you might have to tweak it in order for it to work properly. But it should give you a rough idea.

Comment: Hello, It will just give an error but it will not stop the users from entering more numbers.

Comment: @ashley You can write your own pipe that disallows the entering of more numbers.

Comment: Do you have an example for that? I know angular pipes are used mainly for converting text.

Comment: @ashley Updated answer.

Comment: @ashley Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if this solution works for you. I noticed that you have quite a few questions without an accepted answer. It's always good to mark them as accepted so that they don't appear as unsolved when they are in fact solved. :)

Comment: check out this plunk. https://plnkr.co/edit/06lmBTvTPOSAg3kXaBQO?p=preview It is not working. Can you help?